# Can not include request.ContentLength

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I have a side question that I am struggling with but decided to ask it in a separate question as the original question is long winded and I think the answer to this question will resolve the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084956/request-method-post-not-working/22088182?noredirect=1#comment33529178_22088182). (I will update the other one once both solved)

So I am doing a **HttpWebRequest** on **Visual Studio 2013** and want to add POST to the header.  That works fine but the end server comes back with an error saying that it does not know the length.  So from the code snippets I google I should be able to just code request.ContentLength = byte1 where byte1 is the content length of the head parameters.  But my code wont accept .ContentLength as a paramamter?  WHY??

The [doco](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says I can and I am including **using System.Net** and using **System.Net.Http**

So what am I doing wrong??

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Web;

 private async void VerifyUser()
         {
            loginParams = "username=" + logInUserIdString + "&password=" + logInPasswordString;
            string teamResponse = "https://mySite.com/teambeta/LoginApp?" + loginParams;
            Debug.WriteLine(teamResponse);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(teamResponse);


            request.Method = "POST";

           request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";



            System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                logInString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

           Debug.WriteLine(logInString);
         }
```

NOTE: If I dont include the request.Method = "POST" it will be ok but return nothing of value.  SO I understand too that the default length is -1 but I want to change it to the length of the loginParams.

HELP??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!!

The correct process to do Http web requests and response with Visual Studio 2013 is to use the new [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.  I figured it would be something like but just could not find it.

So here is the correct code to do a Http request to for example log in or in my case to just verify the user is a valid user based on the userID and password.

```
private async void VerifyUser()
{
        loginParams = "username=" + logInUserIdString + "&password=" + logInPasswordString;
        string teamResponse = "https:// mySite.com?" + loginParams;
        Debug.WriteLine(teamResponse);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(teamResponse), null);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine(responseBody);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
            Debug.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
        }
}
```

And thanks heaps to Suvabrata for your help as your comments moved me in the direction that got me to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Post method its likely to have request stream data but in you case it send via URL, so your response stream is empty.

```
request.ContentLength=0;
```

Would be preferable but if you send some data in request stream then just set the character length of the data to ContentLength that will work.

[Update] Code add for help ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

public interface ICommunication
        {
        string Communicate(string Uri,string Method, string Refrance, string ContentType, string Data);
        }

    public class JSONCommunication  :ICommunication
        {
        public JSONCommunication()
            {

            }
        #region ICommunication Members
        private CookieContainer Cookie = new CookieContainer();
        public string Communicate(string Uri, string Method, string Refrance, string ContentType, string Data)
            {
            HttpWebRequest web = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Uri);
            web.Method = Method;
            web.Referer = Refrance;
            web.ContentLength = Data.Length;
            web.CookieContainer = Cookie;
            //web.KeepAlive = true;
            web.ContentType = ContentType;
            if (Data != string.Empty && Method.ToUpper()!="GET")
                {
                using (var Request = web.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                    Request.Write(
                        ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(Data), 
                        0,
                        (int) web.ContentLength);
                    }

                }
            web.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            var Response = web.GetResponse();
            var ResquestStream = Response.GetResponseStream();
            ICollection<byte> bt = new List<byte>();
            while (true)
                {
                int i = ResquestStream.ReadByte();
                if (i == -1)
                    break;
                bt.Add((byte)i);
                }
            var output = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(bt.ToArray());
            return output;
            }

        #endregion
        }
```

Comment: thats exactly what I want to do add the line: request.ContentLength = 0 or what ever it is but .contentLength does not appear to be a valid method in the namespace.   Here is the error I get:       System.Net.HttpWebRequest does not contain a definition for ContentLength and no extension method ContentLength accepting a fist argument of type System.Net.HttpWebRequest could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have only use : System.Net;

Comment: No difference by just having System.Net  Not sure how that could help but I am a newbie so walking blind here